# Laravel 5.1 Assets (js, css, img) on OpenShift don't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, openshift, assets

I uploaded my Laravel 5.1 project to OpenShift and everything is ok.
But when I tried working with css and js files using `{{ asset() }}` an error occurred and the changes are not displayed.

Please help. Thanks.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/materialize/css/materialize.css') }}">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/estilo.css') }}">
```

[image: example.jpg]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhrDN.jpg)

Comment: Please copy paste the error message here

Comment: Hi. This is what shows on the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is the url http://laravel-nevts.rhcloud.com

Comment: Where are those files stored inside your project?

Comment: In the "public" folder, is a laravel project

Comment: Do you have an example of another page on the application? Off the top of my head it may because you don't have mod_rewrite enabled on OpenShift

Comment: Place that `plugins` folder within your `css` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `/` in your `{{ asset('css/estilo.css') }}`

like this `{{ asset('/css/estilo.css') }}`